# Как правильно расширить массив?

Tags: javascript

Создаю массив и сохраняю в localstorage:

```
var myLikes = [];
myLikes[0] = {'slide':'1'}
localStorage.setItem("myCollection", JSON.stringify(myLikes));
```

Потом я хочу добавить новые данные в массив. Пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
var arrayLikes = localStorage.getItem('myCollection')
arrayLikes = [];
arrayLikes.push({'slide':'26'});
```

Но получаю только обновление массива, т.е. с удалением предыдущего значения.

Как мне правильно добавить новые значения в массив?

Comment: Закомментите `arrayLikes = [];`

Comment: В этом случае получаю ошибку в консоле arrayLikes.push is not a function

Comment: JSON.parse кто будет делать-то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При записи значения, используется `JSON.stringify()`, в localStorage записывается **`string`**.
Соответственно, при чтении нужно выполнить обратное преобразование: JSON (строку) - в объект (массив):

```
var arrayLikes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myCollection') || '[]'); 
arrayLikes.push(/*...*/);
```

---

Выражение вида `localStorage.getItem('key') || '[]'` работает следующим образом: если в localStorage отсутствует значение с указанным ключом, то `getItem()` вернет `null` - а так как `null==false`, оператор `||` вернет второй (правый) операнд - json-строку с пустым массивом... которая и станет аргументом `parse()`. Проще говоря: если значение еще не было записано в localStorage, то переменной присвоится пустой массив.

*p.s.: Это не защищает от ошибок парсинга, и более надежным вариантом будет чтение и парсинг в `try..catch`.*

Comment: Прошу прощения, сначала я был невнимателен - а исправляю долго (к сожалению, пишу с мобилки).